# Number of ways of distributing chocolates.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Find the number of ways in which $6$ different chocolates can be distributed among $3$  children such that each of them get atleast one chocolate.

My approach:-
First choose $3$ chocolates and give $1$ to each one of them. This can be done in $\frac{6!}{3!}= 120$ ways. Now each of the remaining $3$ chocolates have $3$ choices each. So these can be distributed in $3*3*3=27$ ways.
So total ways if distributing, $120*27=3240$.
Is my approach correct? And answer? Please help me figure out the right way to do this if my solution is incorrect. Thank you.

Comment: No that is a lot of overcounting. Please use Principle of Inclusion Exclusion or Stirling Number of the second kind - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Comment: @Math Lover, could you please explain it here? I have very little experience in maths, so i don't think i am equipped to understand this thing. Could you please simplify this for me? Please.

Comment: Have you studied Principle of Inclusion Exclusion?

Comment: @Math lover, No ..I haven't

Comment: Read the part which says distribution in non-empty bins - https://brilliant.org/wiki/distinct-objects-into-distinct-bins/. There is an example close to your question - In how many ways can 5 balls, each of a different color, be distributed among 3 distinct urns such that no urn remains empty?

Comment: @Math Lover. Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Math Lover, the answer should work out to 540 right?

Comment: that is correct.

Comment: @math lover, 3240=540*6... What i am still not able to understand is...how i have overcounted in the above approch. Can you please point that out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124913/discussion-between-math-lover-and-ggsvdgdhddh).